how to select multiple count in same query with different conditions
I'm using this query to get count of tickets a user has used in a month.
SELECT
  user_id,
  COUNT(*) AS tickets
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM washtickets WHERE MONTH(used_at) = 3 AND YEAR(used_at) = 2024) AS tickets_month
GROUP BY user_id HAVING tickets >= 1;

Its working fine and returns a list with
user_id  |  tickets_month
-------------------------
xxxx     |  5
xxxx     |  3
...      |  ...

So now I want to compare number of tickets of that month with all tickets the user has used all time.
Something like:
user_id  |  tickets_month  |  all_time_tickets
----------------------------------------
2058     |  5              |  10
...      |  ...            |  ..
...      |  ...            |  ..

Is it possible to get this information in the same query?
Or do I need to make another separated count query?
